# Visual Studio Code extension marked malicious, how to (force) install?

Tags: visual-studio-code, apollo

When I started VS Code today the 'Apollo GraphQL' extension was marked as malicious and removed from my extensions. I would really like to reinstall it, but VS Code wont let me.

[image]

I get the following message when trying to install it from the cli:

```
λ code --force --install-extension apollographql.vscode-apollo
Found 'apollographql.vscode-apollo' in the marketplace.
Installing...
malicious
```

I also tried adding the `--force` argument when installing it through the cli.

Is there any way I can still use this extension?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2018/11/26/event-stream

Comment: They finally fixed the problem. So one can install it again without problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install it until they fix it.

Try and find a similar extension. There are loads of extensions for GraphQL.